# How to find Number of Factors of "product of numbers"

Tags: c, algorithm, prime-factoring

I m trying to find number of factors of product of big numbers.

The problem statement is this : Suppose you are given N numbers(let say N = 10), each number <= 1000000.
How to find the number of factors of the product of such numbers.

Can someone please provide an efficient algorithm for doing this.

Example :

1) N = 3 and Numbers are 3, 5, 7

Ans = 8 (1, 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35, 105)

2) N = 2 and Numbers are 5, 5

Ans = 3 (1, 5 and 25)

Comment: Well, multiply all the numbers, factorize the result, count all divisors?

Comment: Use a sieve to factorise numbers, add counts of each prime factors, then compute product of (n(i)+1) where n(i) is count of the ith prime factor.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz that's for *one number*'s number of divisors.

Comment: Are all of the numbers prime like in your example?

Comment: @H2CO3 : The product can overflow. And its not an efficient method

Comment: @Joni. Its not necessary. But you have to define it in terms of prime factors, as shown in example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editorial for the problem is here

http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/15943/numfact-editorial

```
int total = 0, N = 0, Number;
scanf ("%d", &total);
while (total--)
{
    scanf ("%d", &N);
    map<int, int> Counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &Number);
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= Number; j++)
        {
            while (Number % j == 0)
            {
                Counter[j]++;
                Number /= j;
            }
        }
        if (Number > 1) Counter[Number]++;
    }
    int Answer = 1;
    for (map<int, int>::iterator it = Counter.begin(); it != Counter.end(); it++)
        Answer *= (it->second + 1);
    printf ("%d\n", Answer);
}
```

This got Accepted.

**Sample Inputs and Outputs:**

```
7
3
3 5 7
3
2 4 6
2
5 5
10
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
1
100
10
10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
10
1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000 

8
10
3
11
9
1681
3721
```

Comment: @shek8034 But I couldnt solve it in the competition. Solved it only after reading the editorial :(

Comment: @thefourtheye : Yes. I solved it by doing prime factorization in a very different way, and my code was very clumsy. Now i know, how to solve it efficiently. This is probably the best and standard method to solve this problem.

Comment: @shek8034 another standard trick here is to use 3-smooth numbers for trial divisions, which would make it run in 2/6 of the time. we can enumerate those numbers by `j = 5, + 2, + 4, + 2, + 4, + 2, + 4, + ....`.

Comment: Basically, all the Prime numbers will be around the multiples of 6, except for 2 and 3. This method will greatly improve the performance. I blogged about it sometime back http://www.thefourtheye.in/2012/10/prime-numbers-and-basic-primality-tests.html

Answer (score 5):

Factorize each number into list of prime factors and their multiplicities, `L(n) = { p_i , k_i }`, for a number *n* = **Π** p<sub>i</sub><sup>k<sub>i</sub></sup>. Numer of divisors for such *n* is ND( L(n) ) = **Π** (k<sub>i</sub>+1) a product of all coefficients, each incremented by 1 (this includes 1 and *n* itself as divisors of *n*). This corresponds to picking *none, one, ... k<sub>i</sub>* of each of them to multiply.

To calculate the ND of a product of arbitrary number of numbers, factorize each and merge their factorizations, where in case of matching primes their coefficients are added together. Then calculate the ND of the merged factorization.

To merge many factorizations together, start by merging two of them; then merge the result and the next one; then merge the last result and the next factorization, and so on. This is called *folding*. Or better merge them pairwise, then merge the results in same pairwise fashion, and so on util only one merged result is left. That's similar to how a bottom-up mergesort is done.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply all the numbers, factorize the result, count all divisors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        p *= strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);

    int n = 0;
    int s = sqrt(p) + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
        if (p % i == 0)
            n += 2 - (p / i == i); // obfuscation ;)

    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p` wont be able to hold 1000000 ^ 10. This problem is is not as easy as it seems :(

Comment: @thefourtheye `unsigned long long`? Or are you trying to break RSA with numbers like `10^1000000`?

Comment: Multiplying will not work for this problem. As per the problem statement, 10 number and each of them can be 1000000. There is a different approach. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: "Multiplying will not work for this problem" - WAT? It ***just did.*** But actually you don't have to do it this way, if you leave out the actual calculation of the product, then you'll essentially taking the approach Will Ness suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I am sorry. I shouldn't have said, "Multiplying will not work for this problem". It will work only for small numbers. I included the solution which worked, in my answer. Will Ness's answer is based on Divisor Function only.

Comment: This question should not be downvoted because it's not technically incorrect. "I don't like it" or "the other solution is better" is ***not a goddamn reason for downvoting!***

Comment: @thefourtheye It's not directed towards you - it's directed towards whoever downvoted it.

Comment: and mine. (???) :) btw I didn't "leave out the actual calculation", I did suggest to "calculate the ND of the merged factorization" (and the explanation how to do it was just given above there).

Comment: @thefourtheye there was a fourth answer here, which is now deleted for some reason (users with rep above 10k can see deleted answers), and the user that answered is deleted as well. Usually when a user deletes themselve their answers stay; I guess this deletion was not without some drama, which perhaps included that user downvoting all the other answers (and maybe the question too). The code is similar to yours, with a nice C trick, using static `int prime[1000002];` as your `map`. I would up-vote it; it even uses 3-smooth numbers for trial divisions.

Comment: Ah. It would have been better if SO notifies the users when an answer is written to the question in which the user has contributed. I also would have upvoted it, like I upvoted yours. I believe it would have been faster than mine as it uses Arrays. I ll try that out.